# Remove new lines in JSON string using Newtonsoft JSON.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft JSON.NET to create a dynamic JSON object which looks fine, but is unrecognizable when I send it to a REST API. My best guess is there are new lines in the JSON string which is breaking the process the API uses to parse the data. Is there a way to ensure all new lines are removed from the JSON data I am sending?

```
        dynamic MyPerson = new JObject();
        MyPerson.username = "CodeMonkey";
        MyPerson.first_name = "Monkey";
        MyPerson.last_name = "banana";
        MyPerson.email_address = "bananacrazy@monkey.com";
        MyPerson.is_active = true;


        string PersonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyPerson);
```

The JSON it is returning if I use Response.Write is:

```
{"username":"CodeMonkey","first_name":"Monkey","last_name":"Banana","email_address":"monkey@bananacrazy.com","is_active":true}
```

Comment: Well what does the string in `PersonData` look like? JSON.NET does not do indenting by default.

Comment: if I use Response.Write I get the string above.

Comment: Yeah, so there's no newlines there... You're looking at the wrong cause. Perhaps elaborate on "breaking the process the API uses to parse the data".

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks.

Comment: Blank lines are valid in JSON both interleaved and inside of strings. It sounds like your api provider has defects in their deserializer (or the api is just broken currently)